# Erro: "connection rejected by remote interface" utilizando Firebird 3 em .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, firebird

Tenho uma aplicação em asp.net, que atualmente utiliza o firebird 2.5.1 e 
funciona normalmente. Estou testando a versão 3.0 Release Candidate para 
migrar em breve a versão, porém não abre a conexão, ocorre o seguinte 
erro:

> "connection rejected by remote interface".

Testando em uma aplicação em Delphi funcionou normalmente, porém no Visual  Studio não funciona.

Gostaria de saber se pode ser o provider para .net que ainda não foi 
atualizado para a nova versão, ou se pode ser algo de errado que eu esteja 
fazendo.

Answer (score 2):

**Resposta curta**: reinstala o Firebird server marcando a opção de habilitar *legacy auth*, ou altera a configuração do server (no firebird.conf), mudando a linha

```
#AuthServer = Srp
```

para

```
AuthServer = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi
```

**Resposta longa**:
ADO provider pra .net (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll, v4.10.0.0) ainda não suporta o novo modelo padrão de autenticação do Firebird (SRP), portanto o server deve ser configurado para suportar o modelo legado de autenticação.

A maioria das aplicações Delphi usa a fbclient (ou a gds32.dll) pra se conectar no servidor, e como a instalação do Firebird 3.0 distribui uma fbclient que já implementa o novo modelo de autenticação, as aplicações que usam fbclient não terão esse problema.

---

Caso apareçam outros erros de login depois dessa solução, [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36807946/3337447) cobre todo o problema e a solução completa, bem melhor do que fiz acima (só achei a resposta depois de resolver :-| )

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema de:

> connection rejected by remote interface

Alterando a `GDS32.DLL` na pasta system32, pode ser que o arquivo foi corrompido, algo do tipo. Está rodando normalmente agora, consegui abrir o banco no IB e meu sistema voltou rodar.

Answer (score 0):

Abra o arquivo firebird.conf e modifique os seguintes parâmetros:

```
WireCrypt = Disabled
AuthServer = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi
AuthClient = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi
```

Para Windows existem opções diferentes lá. Basta olhar nos comentários de AuthServer/AuthClient.

Depois reinicie o Firebird ou a máquina.

Answer (score -1):

1. Procure e apague os arquivos GDS32.DLL na pasta SYSWOW64, em System32 e na pasta local do executável (se houver).
2. Copie o arquivo FBCLIENT.DLL e mude o nome da cópia para GDS32.DLL.
3. Copie o novo arquivo GDS32.DLL para as pastas SYSWOW64, System32 e onde mais houver.

Pronto. O erro para.